# Change value of SwitchPreference in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a PreferenceFragmentCompat with switch preferences. One of the preferences requires a permission and I have figured out how to ask for the permission. My problem is that if I have to check for permission, the switch shouldn't change value until the permission result is received, but it does.
So my question is, how do I change the value of the switch in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve EXACTLY that result I think you have to re-write from scratch the SwitchPreference which should wait the "onChanged()" callback result before procede by changing its internal state.

Or you can leave the component in the newer/changed state, and then rollback to previous state ONLY if the Permission is not granted.
Permission request dialogs are not bypassable, so even if the SwitchPreference is already changed, the user cannot do so much in your Activity until he allow or denied the Permission, so it's quite safe to leave the SwitchPreference in a temporary state.

Comment: How do I roll back to the previous state then? Maybe I have to rewrite it

Comment: When the Permission is granted or denied you just set the SwitchPreference in the new or old state respectively from the "onPermissionResult()" (I use quotes because I'm away from computer and I don't remember exactly the name) method.

Comment: But how do I change the state of the view? I can't come up with a way to access the view.

Comment: You work in the Main/UiThread, so you can call normal "getPreference(..)" method from the "onPermissionResult()" and rollback the SwitchPreference state to the previous value if the Permission was not granted.

Comment: The thing is that even if I change back the preference, the switch doesn't change back. So if I click the switch and deny and set the preference to false, the state of the switch is still "on"

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late to the party, but maybe it helps new people with the same problem.

To change the switch state you have to cast the `Preference` to `SwitchPreference`. If you have some extra logic in the corresponding `OnPreferenceChangeListener`, you have to call it manually.

Example (Kotlin):

```
val preference = (findPreference<Preference>(Keys.PUSH_ENABLED) as? SwitchPreference)
preference?.isChecked = isGranted
preference?.callChangeListener(isGranted)
```